# Miss parameter in http post

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

```
NSString * aToken = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"accessToken"] firstObject];
NSString * post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@", @"035571"];
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", aToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

the error is: `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Required field is missing. 'code'"}`

how to fix it? any idea?

Comment: The request parameters are defined by the server endpoint.  Without knowing what you're talking to, we can't really tell you what field you forgot.  But it looks like "code" is the required field.  I see you're setting that in the post body.  Should it be a header?

Comment: I'm not a code validator.  It looks *reasonable*, which is different.  You could use an HTTP proxy, such as FiddlerTool or Charles Proxy, to have a look at the actual HTTP request / response that is being sent over the wire.

Comment: Get Charles Proxy (free trial) and look at the network traffic and see  exactly what is being sent/received.